# Pandas - organize and count unique data

Tags: python, pandas

How to do this with pandas?

I have this dataset, which consists of a list of cars and its colors (cars and colors may repeat):

```
 Color   Car      

 Blue    Honda       
 Green   Honda     
 Green   Honda      
 Blue    fiat             
 Black   fiat    
 ....
 Yellow  nissan
```

I would like to create a column for each car with its respective color (without duplicated colors related to each car). In the example, Honda & green happens twice, but in the honda-column  ” green”  would appear only once.

Something like this:

```
+----------------------+------------+----------------------+---------+
|           Color      |    Car     |   Honda              | Fiat    |
+----------------------+------------+----------------------+---------+
| Blue                 | Honda      |Blue                  |Blue
| Green                |  Honda      Green                 |Black
| Green                | Honda      |Yellow                   
|  Blue                | fiat                                                
|  Black               | fiat            
….
| Yellow               | nissan         
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

I also would like to know how many colors (no duplicate) each car has (amount of unique items in the column "Colar" related to each item in the "Car" column).

Comment: In your output, Car has both Green and Yellow as color (row 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `join` with `pd.crosstab`

```
df1 = df.join(
    pd.crosstab(df.index, df["Car"], df["Color"], aggfunc="first").fillna(" ")
)
```

---

```
print(df1)
    Color     Car  Honda   fiat  nissan
0    Blue   Honda   Blue               
1   Green   Honda  Green               
2   Green   Honda  Green               
3    Blue    fiat          Blue        
4   Black    fiat         Black        
5  Yellow  nissan                Yellow
```

For unique colors according to your example output we can create a boolean mask and apply this back to the values parameter in `pd.crosstab`

```
unique_color = np.where(
    df.groupby(['Car','Color']).cumcount().ge(1), "", df["Color"]
)

df1 = df.join(pd.crosstab(df.index, df["Car"], unique_color, aggfunc="first").fillna(" ")
       )
```

---

```
print(df1)

   Color     Car  Honda   fiat  nissan
0    Blue   Honda   Blue               
1   Green   Honda  Green               
2   Green   Honda                      
3    Blue    fiat          Blue        
4   Black    fiat         Black        
5  Yellow  nissan                Yellow
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! But how can I make the out put to be filled just with unique values for each column? (for example, in the Honda column the color "green" would only appear once)